I'm trying to replace a word on a PDF but it's returning an error
I'm currently trying to substitute a word in a PDF, i'm using fitz because it was the library that i got the closer to fixing the problem but i'm stuck. heres the code:
import fitz

doc = fitz.open([FILE HERE])
for page in doc:
    areas = page.search_for("Férias")
    print(page)
    for area in areas:
        writer = fitz.TextWriter(page, area)
        writer.write_text("Vacations", fontsize=10, fontname="helv", color=(1, 1, 0))

And here is the error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13768\3906041629.py in ?()
      2 for page in doc:
      3     areas = page.search_for("Férias")
      4     print(page)
      5     for area in areas:
----> 6         writer = fitz.TextWriter(page, area)
      7         writer.write_text("Vacations", fontsize=10, fontname="helv", color=(1, 1, 0))
      8 

c:\Users\hh100801\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fitz\__init__.py in ?(self, page_rect, opacity, color)
  12983         self.this = mupdf.fz_new_text()
  12984 
  12985         self.opacity = opacity
  12986         self.color = color
> 12987         self.rect = Rect(page_rect)
  12988         self.ctm = Matrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, self.rect.height)
  12989         self.ictm = ~self.ctm
  12990         self.last_point = Point()

c:\Users\hh100801\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\fitz\__init__.py in ?(self, p0, p1, x0, y0, x1, y1, *args)
  10946 
  10947         Explicit keyword args p0, p1, x0, y0, x1, y1 override earlier settings
  10948         if not None.
...
  20513     if p0 is not None:  ret_x0, ret_y0 = get_xy(p0)
  20514     if p1 is not None:  ret_x1, ret_y1 = get_xy(p1)
  20515     if x0 is not None:  ret_x0 = x0

I was trying to replace a word on a PDF

Your code has multiple problems. (1) You cannot replace text by writing new text to the same place: first you must remove what has been written there. (2) You cannot change the area occupied by original content. You new word is longer and won't fit. (3) TextWriter write() has no argument "fontname". Look at these example scripts instead: script1, script2. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.
